# mongo $sort $aggregate get different result on each execution

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'm executing an aggregate query to obtain all the unique names for each document. (The name could be repeatedly and that is okay).

The problem is that each time that I executed the query I receive a different result.

Collection example:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dds82d99b912454cba84359"),
    "name": "name1",
    "creation_date: 2019-03-07T00:00:00.000Z
}
```

Query:

```
db.getCollection("collection_name").aggregate([
        { 
            "$match": {
            "creation_date": {
                $gte: ISODate("2019-03-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
                $lte: ISODate("2019-09-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
                }
            }
        },
        {
            '$group': {
                '_id': null, 'array': {'$addToSet': '$$ROOT.name'}
            },
        },
        {'$sort': {'creation_date': 1, '_id':1}}
]);
```

I have a couple of records with exactly the same creation_date, for that reason, I also try to order the results by the _id field but the problem persists :/

Any idea of why I obtain different results on each execution?

Comment: May you should $sort before $group.
When you group you lose creation_date and _id

Comment: When you group it, there is no creation_date. If you need to sort by creation date, you need to get it also